# @fontface not working on server but on localhost

Tags: css, font-face

I dont know why my fontface isn't working. It works on my web developer but when i uploaded it to my web server, it does not show despite same code and directory
I tried using firebug to zoom in the problem but to not avail.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'FuturaCondensedMedium';

src: url('/fonts/FuturaCondensedMedium.eot');

src: local('☺'), url('/fonts/FuturaCondensedMedium.woff') format('woff'), url('/fonts/FuturaCondensedMedium.ttf') format('truetype'),
 url('/fonts/FuturaCondensedMedium.svg') format('svg');
}

body   
{
    background: #ffffff;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family:'FuturaCondensedMedium';
    color: #59595d; 
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you uploaded the font also ?

Comment: The usual questions: have you checked that the fonts are uploaded, is the `/fonts/` folder in your root folder, etc?

Comment: Firebug (or equivalent dev tools) are the first step to debug this. If you look in the network tab do you see the font files requested and loaded okay? Or do they error?

Comment: yup i did, i tried downloading it too

Comment: What is the problem? The page shows Futura-CondensedMedium on Firefox, where I can conveniently check the actual fonts used, and looks pretty much the same on Chrome and IE. Always identify the browser(s) tested in matters like this.

Comment: yea, i just managed to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked your paths and the `/fonts/` folder is indeed in the root folder, so all good there. But in checking for the existence of the font files, both of these did not exist:

```
/fonts/FuturaCondensedMedium.woff

/fonts/FuturaCondensedMedium.svg
```

Make sure they have actually been uploaded.

Comment: thanks for the hint! actually these files are there but they are inaccessible due to the MIME thing which does not recognize the file extension. After some research, all i need to do is to add a few lines to my web.config file. thanks!

Comment: Ah, right. That's good to know. I've seen so many problems with `@font-face`, but not come across that one before.